# FillRect() not working

Tags: java, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make a program where green squares are drawn in a JFrame, however when I try it the squares aren't visible. I don't know whether they are not being drawn at all or just not visible for some reason.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //make sure nothing happens when at main menu
    if(level >= 1)
    {
        //determine square size
        size[0] = playScreen.getWidth() / squares;
        size[1] = playScreen.getHeight() / squares;
        System.out.println("The width of a single square is " + size[0]);
        System.out.println("The height of a single square is " + size[1]);
        //draw the cubes
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        if(currentView == 0)
        {
            //front view
            for(int i = 0; i < xPosTargets.size(); i++)
            {
                g.fillRect(xPosTargets.get(i)*size[0], zPosTargets.get(i)*size[1], size[0], size[1]);
            }
        }
        else if(currentView == 1)
        {
            //side view
            for(int i = 0; i < xPosTargets.size(); i++)
            {
                g.fillRect((yPosTargets.get(i))*size[0], (zPosTargets.get(i))*size[1], size[0], size[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //top view
            for(int i = 0; i < xPosTargets.size(); i++)
            {
                g.fillRect((xPosTargets.get(i))*size[0], (squares - zPosTargets.get(i))*size[1], size[0], size[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have thought of the variables having an incorrect value, but when I try to print them all with `System.out.println()`, they are exactly what they should be. The variable types are as follows:
`xPosTargets`, `yPosTargets` and `zPosTargets` are `ArrayList<Integer>`s
`size` is an `int[]`
`playScreen` is a `JPanel`
`squares` is an `int`, and yes, it does actually have a value when it should be painting for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `paint(Graphics g)` instead of `paintComponent(Graphics g)`?

Comment: I hate it when things seem to be a LOT easier than I think... Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you want a more in-depth understanding of painting in Java, take a look at this link. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: I've added some JButtons to the frame, but they are invisible after the paint runs, until I go over them with my mouse. Do you know how to fix this or do I have to ask a new question for it?

Comment: I don't know the exact context of your issue, but try Googling "jbuttons invisible until mouseover", plenty of other posts avilable that may help you.